# Compiling player/stage on Mac os x

Tags: macos, postgresql, linker, player-stage

Not sure if any had this problem or similar but if you have some help would be appreciated.

I have setup postgresql in the following location and set the link path to /usr/local/pgsql-9.0. Also setup the libpqxx in the /usr/local/lib

But I am guessing the error says that it cant find the postgresql anywhere. Is that correct ?

```
Linking CXX shared library libplayerdrivers.dylib Undefined symbols:   "_PQntuples", referenced from:
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o   "_PQresultErrorMessage", referenced from:
      Postlog::rollback() constin postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o   "_PQgetvalue", referenced from:
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerInfo(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o "_PQexecParams", referenced from:
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o   "_PQresultStatus", referenced from:
      Postlog::rollback() constin postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerInfo(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o "_PQexec", referenced from:
      Postlog::rollback() constin postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerInfo(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o "_PQgetlength", referenced from:
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerInfo(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o "_PQbinaryTuples", referenced from:
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o   "_PQclear", referenced from:
      Postlog::rollback() constin postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      Postlog::storeData(int, char const*, void const*, double, unsigned short, unsigned short, unsigned char, unsigned char)in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::WriteLayerData(LayerDataHolder&) in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerData(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetLayerInfo(char const*)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o
      PostgresConn::GetVectorMapInfo(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)in dbconn.o "_PQsetdbLogin", referenced from:
      Postlog::Setup()     in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::Connect(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*)in dbconn.o   "_PQstatus", referenced from:
      Postlog::Setup()     in postlog.o
      Postlog::isConnected() const in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::Connected()      in postgis.o
      PostgresConn::Connect(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*)in dbconn.o   "_PQfinish", referenced from:
      Postlog::Shutdown()     in postlog.o
      Postlog::~Postlog()in postlog.o
      Postlog::~Postlog()in postlog.o
      Postlog::~Postlog()in postlog.o
      PostgresConn::Disconnect()       in dbconn.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Comment: Looks more like you're not linking the PostgreSQL libraries at all. If the linker couldn't find a specified library then you'd get something closer to "file not found". You should have `-lpqxx -lpq` in your linker command somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to "mu is too short" its indeed the missing -lpq

Looks like there is a bug with the player/stage build for Mac Os X